# I need to get a URL for data (html)

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am looking to get the Player ID at the end of a URL that looks exactly in this format, most of the time:

```
website.domain/get?key=Player_1637114231
```

I need to get the ID at the end (`1637114231`). How would I do this in my HTML page?

Comment: You can't. You need a programming language.

Comment: i have everything set up; i just need a way to get the domain URL from the website I created

Comment: After that comment, I have even less idea about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i need the id at the end of that URL (1637114231 was the ID for this) so I can incorporate the data into the title/body

Comment: @SpencerDevv Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: @SpencerDevv — HTML can't do that. You need a programming language.

Comment: yes and no; i know Node.js but not true JavaScript

Comment: @SpencerDevv — Node.js runs "true" JavaScript. You can generate your HTML from Node.js. Express.js will help.

Comment: ok then; guess im going straight res.write()'s then lol :D

Comment: I alr made the Webserver and i have it hosted too; I just want the website not to be looking like crap

Comment: @Quentin Oh i just thought of how I can do it I think; is it possible to change a title for a HTTP in a node.js script

Comment: @SpencerDevv I added an answer, check if that works?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman if i wanted to make that a title; is it possible for me to go (outside of <script>:

`<title>PlayerData | id</title>`

Comment: @SpencerDevv Yes, you can set it by setting `document.title = "PlayerData | " + id;`

Comment: @SpencerDevv Updated your question to make it better to understand and added JavaScript tag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JavaScript, you can use the following code to grab the current URL and parse the part you need!

1. The `location.href` will give you the complete URL.
2. The `location.search` will give you the params: `?key=Player_1637114231`
3. Now remove the `?key=Player_` so that you can get the desired output with added `+` for integer conversion.

Here's the code you need:

```js
const id = +location.search.replace("?key=Player_", "");
```

This is assuming that your URL is always `?key=Player_XXXX`, where `XXXX` is any number of any length and not any other parameters.

Here's a demo:

```js
// On your page, use:
// const { search } = location;
const search = "?key=Player_1637114231";
console.log(+search.replace("?key=Player_", ""));
```